# jQuery remove last-child of a class

Tags: jquery

I am working on a dynamic form, the rows are having parent dropdowns, and when we select a parent it adds new ROWs for number of childs, I have given classes to each child rows. There is option of dynamically adding a parent row, and so on.

So far adding and deleting the parent rows are working fine. I am having trouble removing the last child row

below is a rough idea of how the rows are created, the

```
  Row 1: <parent> select
  Row 2: -<child> select
  Row 3: -<child> select
  Row 4: - Child Add row / Remove row
  Row 5: <parent> select
  Row 6: -<child> select
  Row 7: - Child Add row / Remove row
  Row 8: Parent Add row / remove row
```

for better idea here is the screenshot

[image]

This table is simple, no nested tables, only 6 columns and 12 rows, the indenting is done via css

Now if I use `$('tr.partnumber_2_sub');` in console of firebug, i can see result like

```
Object[tr.partnumber_2_sub, tr.partnumber_2_sub, tr.partnumber_2_sub]
```

but when i use `$('tr.partnumber_2_sub:last-child');` it output empty object. I want to remove the last child and my guess was to `$('tr.partnumber_2_sub:last-child').remove();` but it is not working.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers for the last row, but i realized that my child add row / del row are also having same class on tr. Now i have to remove 2nd last element

**EDIT**

Okay, i have added extra class on tr of child row, and didnt added it add / del of child so now I can use them separately. changed back the title and accepted the answer.

Than you all

Comment: Did you try `$('tr.partnumber_2_sub').last().remove();`

Comment: :) and it worked. Post this as answer so i can accept it. I love stackoverflow

Comment: Seems someone already "stole" it and posted it, just accept that answer, as it is correct!

Comment: i tried to accept that time and it said to do that after 4 minutes, and meanwhile my requirements are changed. See updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$('tr.partnumber_2_sub').last().remove()
```